# Append timestamp and move a file C#

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I'm trying to move and rename a file by appending a timestamp to the name in the following way:

```
private void MoveFile(string from, string to, string filename) {

    File.Move(from, System.IO.Path.Combine(to, filename + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(":", "-")));
}
```

I call it like this:

```
MoveFile(currentPath, outputFolderPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(currentPath));
```

This results in the following exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in
>   mscoorlib.dll.

It works if I remove the appending of the timestamp. Why do I get this error?

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(":", "-")` => `29/09/2019 21-32-07` - the `/` are causing the issue

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia Spot on, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use your function like this:

```
MoveFile(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\IMG_5628.png", @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop", "IMG_5628.png");
```

then your path will look like this:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\IMG_5628.png30.09.2019 2-33-34
```

Change your function as follows:

```
    MoveFile(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\IMG_5628.png", @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop", "IMG_5628.png");

    private void MoveFile(string from, string to, string filename)
    {
        File.Move(from, System.IO.Path.Combine(to, System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss") + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename)));
    }
```

And the path to your file will be valid.

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\IMG_56282019-30-9--02-39-03.png
```